# Cos'era questo "carrozzone"?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *La Storia*, di Elsa Morante, ho letto:

> Inoltre, soprattutto per confortare Nora, aveva fatto acquisto di una radio, cosí che alla sera potevano ascoltare assieme le Opere, delle quali erano entrambi appassionati, fino dal tempo che andavano agli spettacoli del **carrozzone**.

Non riesco a capire cosa fosse questo "carrozzone" dove, a quanto pare, si rappresentavano le opere. E non ho trovato nessuna informazione al riguardo. Qualcuno di voi saprebbe spiegare in che cosa consisteva?

Un altro riferimento a questo "carrozzone" che appare precedentemente nel testo è questo (il corsivo appare nel romanzo):

> Ma piú di tutti al mondo amava Iduzza e Noruzza, per le quali era capace perfino di comporre madrigali. A Nora, da fidanzati, diceva: «Mia stella d’Oriente!» e alla Iduzza (già voluta *Aida*) cantava spesso (N.B. sia lui che Nora erano stati assidui agli spettacoli del ***carrozzone*** lirico di passaggio):  
>                 
>        
>        
>        
>      
>   «Celeste Aida forma divina»...

Comment: Potrebbe trattarsi di una compagnia di teatro ambulante?

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Ho aggiunto un po' più di informazione.

Comment: Un po’ come “il carrozzone” di Renato zero http://testicanzoni.mtv.it/testi-Renato-Zero_17677/testo-Il-Carrozzone-1838174

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dal Sabatini Coletti per [carrozzone](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/C/carrozzone.shtml):

> Grosso rimorchio sistemato ad abitazione: *c. del circo, degli zingari*

e Hoepli riporta:

> Grosso veicolo usato per gli spostamenti dai nomadi, spec. dei circhi

Il termine carrozzone quindi si riferisce a quello del circo ma per estensione anche a compagnie di spettacolo itineranti che erano caratteristiche nella prima metà del '900.

Come fa correttamente notare @Gio, anche nella canzone *[Il carrozzone](https://significatotestocanzone.blogspot.com/2014/12/il-carrozzone-renato-zero.html)* di Renato Zero viene fatto riferimento al carrozzone del circo, anche se in questo caso è da intendersi come metafora del "circo della vita" che, nonostante tutto, va avanti per la sua strada con il suo spettacolo, nel suo ciclo infinito.